# Why is dpi ignored in wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Why is the --dpi argument ignored for the following case?

I'm using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt) if that matters.

I found this related issue but surprised the problem would still exist years later:
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2579

temp.html content:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <style>
                    h1 {
                            font-size: 60px;
                            border-bottom: 2px solid black;
                    }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

--dpi gets ignored even if I specify --disable-smart-shrinking.
cat temp.html | wkhtmltopdf  --debug-javascript --margin-top 0 --margin-left 0 --margin-right 0 --dpi 300 - test_100.pdf
[image]

cat temp.html | wkhtmltopdf  --debug-javascript --margin-top 0 --margin-left 0 --margin-right 0 --dpi 100 - test_300.pdf
[image]

Comment: In some posts I see it works fine with v0.11, but not with v0.12.